# Unable to update table

Tags: java, mysql, date, jdbc

I have ArrayList which holds Object array 0,1,2. I am using enhanced for loop
to print values from it. it works fine and in the same loop when I am trying to 
insert all the values into MySQL table unable to execute the prepared statement and throws nullpointer exception

I have tried to print message after each line and it throws nullpointer exception but i am able to print all the dates inside the same loop without queries. In my MySQL table, I have a date column which is date_details

i have created date column and trying to upload after converting each value from object to String using obj.toString(); then also the same problem

```
    class InsertData
    {
        static void updateTable(ArrayList<Object[]> li)
        {
            PreparedStatement ps = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;
            Connection con = null;
            int count=0;
            try{
                con = DBConnector.getConnection();
                for (Object[] data : li) 
                {
                    System.out.println(data[1]+" "+data[2]+" "+data[0]);
                    //i am able to print all the values in data[0] without queries in normal loop
    String query = "insert into user_data(date_details)values(?)";
                    ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
                    System.out.println("set dt "+data[0]);
                    ps.setString(1, data[0].toString());
                    System.out.println("set dt "+data[0]);//Stopped executing from this line
                    ps.execute();
                }
            }
        }

data[o] holds below date values

    06/01/2013 04:03.36 AM
    06/01/2013 07:06.42 AM
    06/01/2013 12:02.42 AM
```

Comment: Mod warning: Quit arguing in the comments. This applies to both people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your value in insert is the first parameter so you should use 1 and not 3

```
String query =  "insert into user_data(date_details) values(?)";
                ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
                ps.setString(1, data[0].toString());
                ps.execute();
```

*assuming your date_details column is compatible with the string value you pass as in param*

if you are using a date column try using

```
java.sql.Date d = java.sql.Date.valueOf(data[0].toString());
String query =  "insert into user_data(date_details) values(?)";
                ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
                ps.setDate(1, d);
                ps.execute();
```

Comment: @Guru do not hassle people in the comments, it's not how the site works. I'm giving you informal warnings as you're new to the site. If it continues you need to realise it becomes harassment and we do not accept that.

Comment: I have updated my table with varchar and inserted successfully, if i need any other format i will work with java code to convert as per requirement rather wastig time on queries. thanks much @scaisEdge for your time.

Comment: Sure bro but can you please vote for my question which downvoted by mistake by someone, and can you please give me an idea i have three columns id, salary,location in my database  i am fetching easily but how to sort all those three by salary while getting bro ..?